# How many halfscreen images can I add to an animated UIImageView before performance would start to suck?

Tags: iphone

Does anyone have experience with this? I didn't try because I have no appropriate imagery for this, right now. But I wonder if the iPod touch is capable of displaying a fluid, movie-like animation out of fullscreen images (300 x 270)? I fear performance would suck dramatically.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a limit off hand, but this kind of question is best solved by just simply trying it.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible but the total image sizes are a memory issue.  That 300 X 270 images will require 324K each times the number of images is the main problem.

Comment: 324K what? How did you calculate that?